# Is there a way to create multiple static cardviews (defined directly in the layout xml) without the use of a dynamic adapter?

Tags: android, adapter, android-cardview, cardview

Is there a way to create multiple static cardviews (defined directly in the layout xml) in android without the use of a dynamic adapter?

I have a Weather JSON object that I'm trying to parse using retrofit and I want to feed the data to static cardviews in stead of building an adapter for the same.

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerSmall1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentLarge1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSmall1"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerSmall2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentLarge2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSmall2"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView3"
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerSmall3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentLarge3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSmall3"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView4"
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerSmall4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentLarge4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSmall4"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView5"
    android:layout_below="@id/openweather"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerSmall5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentLarge5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSmall5"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, you can add the CardView just fine in your XML file. If the card is big, you might have issues where it doesn't automatically scroll. In that case you could wrap it in a ScrollView or whatever fits your purpose.

Comment: I have tried defining multiple cardviews in a very basic LinearLayout but only one just shows on the app.

Comment: could you add your xml in your original post?

Comment: I did..edited the post

Comment: set orientation to vertical lol

Comment: Got it thanks..lol..hate UI